# Web response returns random symbols in console but not when saved to file

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am trying to make a web request to an api which returns a JSON file with all products. My problem is that when I receive the response it contains random '?' like this:

```
"name":"Ri?pple? L/S ?Te?e","id":303071
```

However when I save the response to a text document or set it to clipboard and paste it the '?' are gone. This problem only happens with the item name.

Here is my code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json");
request.Method = "GET";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A403 Safari/602.1";


HttpWebResponse response = null;
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader _str2 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
string html = _str2.ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine(html); //Writes response to console. (Contains '?')

string destPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "mobile.txt");
File.WriteAllText(destPath, html, Encoding.UTF8); //Saves response to file (Doesn't containt '?')
```

I have asked someone for a solution and he said it should work if I encode it as utf-8 which I am doing as seen in the code but the issue is still there when writing to console. Also if I try to do string.replace the '?' still remain.

Comment: It works fine when I run it on my machine. And it also works fine at https://dotnetfiddle.net/M3PfQF .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Console.WriteLine(html);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that replaces the '?' with spaces.